# How to enable more shipping methods for Nominal Items/Recurring Profile products

Tags: shipping, recurring

Magento Documentation notes: 
"The list of available shipping methods during the shopping cart checkout is restricted to the fixed only (Fixed, Table Rates, and Free)."

I'm wondering if there is a way to change this? I have an extension that enables "In-store pick up" shipping method and it's not displaying as an option when checking out with a nominal item.

Thanks

Comment: have you solved this? Any tip? :D

Answer (score 5):

To enable the shippingmethod for a recurring profile product you need to add the following line to the shipping method model (as seen in `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrate`):

```
   protected $_isFixed = true;
```

The check is done by `addItem()` in `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Address_Rate_Collection`, when there is a nominal item in the cart the FixedOnlyFilter is set to true in the function `getShippingRatesCollection()` in `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address`.

The default for $_isFixed for shippingmethods that extend the `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract` is false so you need to set it in the shipping model to get it enabled.

Comment: do you see any side-effect with this change?